# Why is there a "Identifier is undefined error " even after it's been defined?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, undeclared-identifier

I've created a header file `ll.h` with 2 classes in it. The code goes something like this:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class N{
public:
   int data;
    N *next;
 public:
     N(int);
     ~N();
  };

  class ll{
  public:
      N *head;
  public:
      ll();
      ~ll();
      void aFr(N*);
      void aEn(N*);
   };

  N::N (int d){
  data = d;
  next = NULL;
  }

  N::~N{}

  ll::ll(){
  head = NULL;
  }

  ll::~ll(){}

  void aFr(N* n){
  n->next = head; //identifier "head" undefined
  head = n;
  }

 void aEn(N* n){
 if (head == NULL)// identifier "head" undefined
 {
 head = n;
 n->next = NULL;
 }
 }
```

The `head` in both the function seems like it should not invoke any errors though.

I'm still a beginner so forgive me if it's something trivial.

I know it shouldn't be a problem but I was using different windows for both the classes and the declaration themselves.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 run the code.

Comment: Note: You should put function definitions in source file (`.cpp`) and include your header with `#include "ll.h"` in that source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Here:

```
N::~N{}
```

you forgot [the *parentheses*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_definition) of the destructor `~N()`:

```
N::~N(){};
```

2) Here:

```
void aFr(N* n){
```

and here:

```
void aEn(N* n){
```

You forgot to [use *scope resolution operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup#Class_members) to denote the functions as methods of `class ll`

```
void ll::aFr(N* n){
n->next = head; //identifier "head" undefined
head = n;
}

void ll::aEn(N* n){
if (head == NULL)// identifier "head" undefined
{
head = n;
n->next = NULL;
}
}
```

This compiles fine after these changes.

Comment: Thanks this helped I forgot to add the scope resolutions for both the functions. Since they were in different.cpp files from the declarations i didn't notice them.

Comment: @NithinK Indeed friend. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot class method declaration (ll:) for methods aFR and aEn

```
 void ll::aFr(N* n){
  n->next = head; //identifier "head" undefined
  head = n;
  }

 void ll::aEn(N* n){
 if (head == NULL)// identifier "head" undefined
 {
 head = n;
 n->next = NULL;
 }
 }
```